# Compare Strings avoiding NullPointerException

Tags: java, string, comparison

When I code I often have to compare two Strings. I know that calling `string.equals()` throws a [`java.lang.NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) if the `String` is `null`, so what I always do is:

```
if (string != null && string.equals("something") {
    // Do something
}
```

This results in having lots of methods that always contains a condition whether a `String` is `null` or not.

I would like to avoid this repetition without having an error thrown, is it possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just do:

```
if ("something".equals(string)) {
    // Do something
}
```

This will prevent throwing a [`java.lang.NullPointerException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) since the `Object` who calls `equals()` is not `null`.

Comment: What if both strings are null?

Comment: @saumilsdk It is not possible to call `null.equals(string)`. In case both Strings are a variable you need to call `!= null` on the first one in order to avoid the exception.

Comment: Is there a better solution using Optional in that case?

Comment: if you are looking for a different option, https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#equals-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-